# IIS FTP Server Slow on Fast connection

Tags: iis, azure, windows-server-2016

Running on Azure with a 2 Gbps up/down connection but can only get 10 Mbps download from the IIS FTP server. There don't appear to be any throttling options in IIS FTP settings. Latest version of Windows Server and IIS. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you trying to download from? Which is Azure region and your region? Go to this [page](https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Download) and run a download test from the same Azure region you have, it gives you an idea what will be download rate.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer speed will depend on the Azure Region where you are hosting the IIS FTP server and where you are located on the client side for connectivity, the further the FTP client software is physically from your IIS FTP service will greatly lower your effective throughput for the file transfer speed. There are commercial and open source file transfer software options to work around this issue. I work for FileCatalyst and we provide a solution for slow FTP over fat international networks.